# devexpress gridview control with password column

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress, mask, gridcontrol

I have a simple DevExpress gridview in winform application, I keep passwords in the grid and I want them to be look liked "*******" when the password cell is not focuesed. if the cell is focused, I want to display the real password.

I have this code on Form Load

```
 txtPasswordGridColumn.PasswordChar='*';
```

I wanted to remove '*' when cell is focused but couldnt find the proper event on grid.And if I remove the PasswordChar, then I suppose it will display all passwords since PasswordChar is removed from the COLUMN. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GridView has plenty of suitable events: `FocusedRowChanged`, `FocusedColumnChanged`, `ShownEditor`,...